# Is $\sqrt{f(x) \cdot g(x)} = \sqrt{ f(x) }\cdot \sqrt{g(x)}$?

Tags: functions

**Simple Question:** If two functions $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ are provided, Wolfram Alpha suggests that $\sqrt{f(x)\cdot g(x)}$ is only equal to $\sqrt{f(x)}\cdot\sqrt{g(x)}$ when $x > 0$.

I searched "Is (f(x)^(1/2*g(x)^(1/2)) = ((f(x)*g(x))^(1/2)) ?"

May you please explain this condition?

Thank you.

Comment: `Wolfram Alpha suggests that ...` Please quote what you literally typed into WA.

Comment: Sure thing: I searched "Is (f(x)^(1/2)*g(x)^(1/2)) = ((f(x)*g(x))^(1/2)) ?"

Comment: Assuming you meant [`Is (f(x)^(1/2)*g(x)^(1/2)) = ((f(x)*g(x))^(1/2)) ?`](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Is+(f(x)%5E(1%2F2)*g(x)%5E(1%2F2))+%3D+((f(x)*g(x))%5E(1%2F2))+%3F) the WA answer I see is "$\sqrt{f(x)} \sqrt{g(x)}$ *is not always equal to* $\sqrt{f(x) g(x)}$" which is not the same as what you quoted.

Comment: @dxiv if you wait for it to load, it says it is true when $x>0$ ... probably a bug in WA

Comment: @ZubinMukerjee All I get after the wait is "*Standard computation time exceeded...*". If it does indeed say it's true for $x \gt 0$ then it must be a WA bug, indeed.

Comment: @OswaldChisala For real functions what *is* true is that $\sqrt{f(x) \cdot g(x)} = \sqrt{\,|f(x)|\,} \cdot \sqrt{\,|g(x)|\,}$.

Comment: Rather than speaking of whether $x>0$ or $x\ge0,$ one should speak of whether $f(x)\ge0$ and $g(x)\ge0. \qquad$

Comment: @dxiv See the screenshot. I think if you refresh a few times you might get the same output ... @ MichaelHardy Yes, that is probably what they meant to write.

Comment: @ZubinMukerjee +1 for that. As a side thought, I would add a note to the complex case making it plenty clear that $\,\sqrt{\cdot}\,$ denotes the principal value of the complex square root in that case.

Answer (score 4):

The condition is not correct: for example, let

$$f(x) = -2$$

$$g(x) = -8$$

Then, when $x=1$, which satisfies $x>0$, we get

$$\sqrt{f(x)g(x) }= \sqrt{-2 \cdot -8} = \sqrt{16} = 4$$

but

$$\sqrt{f(x)}\sqrt{g(x)} = \sqrt{-2}\sqrt{-8} = \left(i\sqrt{2} \right)\left(i\sqrt{8}\right)= -4$$

> assuming [principal square roots](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PrincipalSquareRoot.html), as opposed to $-i\sqrt{2}$ and $-i\sqrt{8}$

---

For what it's worth, I put in the same query and got the same erroneous result:

[image: Wolfram|Alpha output]

> Alternate form assuming $x>0$: $\sqrt{f(x)}\sqrt{g(x)}$ is always equal to $\sqrt{f(x)g(x)}$

It's probably a bug in Wolfram|Alpha.

---

As Michael Hardy has pointed out, if $f(x) \geq 0$ and $g(x) \geq 0$, then it is always true that $$\sqrt{f(x)}\sqrt{g(x)} = \sqrt{f(x) g(x)}$$

I think it's likely that this positive-radicand case is what Wolfram|Alpha is intended to output for the "alternate form" section.

Comment: Thanks Zubin, there's a good chance you're right about it being a bug. Kudos.